# Testing if a method passed as a props is called on Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am passing a method, which changes the parent's state to a child (I know, Redux does this better, but that's just for testing).

This is my child component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class RemoveTaskBtn extends Component {
    render() {
        const {removeTask, task} = this.props;
        return (
            <button
                onClick={() => removeTask(task)}
            >
                Remove
            </button>
        );
    }
}

RemoveTaskBtn.propTypes = {
    task: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default RemoveTaskBtn;
```

and this is my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Remove_task_btn from './Remove_task_btn';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import {configure} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe('<RemoveTaskBtn/>', function () {
    let wrapper;
    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = shallow(
            <Remove_task_btn
                removeTask={() => {
                }}
                task={{text: 'test'}}
            />
        );
    })
    it('should call removeTask onClick',
        function () {
            wrapper
                .find('button')
                .simulate('click');
            console.log(wrapper.props())
            expect(wrapper.props().onClick)
                .toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
        });
})
```

But it doesn't work right now.

I get this error:

```
  ● <RemoveTaskBtn/> › should call removeTask onClick

    expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalledTimes()

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type:  function
    Received has value: [Function onClick]

      26 |             console.log(wrapper.props())
      27 |             expect(wrapper.props().onClick)
    > 28 |                 .toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
         |                  ^
      29 |         });
      30 | })

      at Object.toHaveBeenCalledTimes (src/components/Remove_task_btn.test.js:28:18)
```

And this is the response from a `console.log(wrapper.props())`:

```
console.log src/components/Remove_task_btn.test.js:26
      { onClick: [Function: onClick], children: 'Remove' }
```

So what I'm asking is how should I even test it? If I was to mock the function, I'd have to call it manually, rendering the whole test pointless.

So my question is: How can I check if a method passed as a prop was called on click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mock the function and pass it in props, then verify it has been called like :

```
const removeTaskMock = jest.fn();
wrapper = shallow(
        <Remove_task_btn
            removeTask={removeTaskMock}
            task={{text: 'test'}}
        />
    );
```

And then in your test :

```
expect(removeTaskMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to [mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) the function like this:

```
const mockCallback = jest.fn(x => 42 + x);
```

Now if you pass this function into your components as props like this:

```
removeTask={mockCallback}
```

And now you can test it with:

```
expect(mockCallback.mock.calls.length).toBe(2);
```

Obviously, you need to change the function to fit your use case.
Hope this helps. Happy coding.