# Test that React prop method has not been called with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

> How do I test a prop(callback) function that is called conditionally
>   I have a component which passes a prop function to its child on a condition like:

```
if(this.props.myFun) {
  this.props.myFun();
}
```

to test this, I have two cases here:
1. Where the prop is passed to the component

```
 <ChildComp myFun={value => value } /> and I can test it from the child-
const comp = mountWithIntl(<ChildComp myFun={value => value } />);
expect(comp.instance().props.myFun).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

> 2. Where the prop is not passed: I trying like

```
const comp = mountWithIntl(<MyComp />);
expect(comp.instance().props.myFun).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But, Since If I mock the prop while mounting the component, the 
   method will be called. But how do I test the undefined or unmocked 
   prop?
   If I dont pass the prop and do:

```
expect(comp.instance().props.myFun).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I will get:

> jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy

which I cant do as per my code
   please help

Comment: myFun will be undefined, so how could it possibly have been called? If you have some method inside MyComp that calls myFun, then you should test that method instead.

Comment: As Ricardo mentioned myFun will be undefined so you can always check:
``` expect(comp.instance().props.myFun).toBeUndefined(); ```

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I had to test expect(comp.instance().props.myFun).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
just it is not covered in test coverage
toBeUndefined() worked for me. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing if a method passed as a props is called on Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355151/testing-if-a-method-passed-as-a-props-is-called-on-click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can test that a not passed function does not get called. What you can do to test if it is get rendered without that function. That should be enough