# Is there a way to test if an empty React prop has not been called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme, sinon

I have a React component that receives an optional `onApply` prop, like below:

```js
export default function App({ onApply }) {
  const handleApply = () => {
    if (onApply) onApply();
  };

  return <button onClick={handleApply}>Apply</button>;
}
```

I'm trying to write a test that asserts if this prop has not been called if it has not been provided to the component. The following is my test's current code:

```js
describe("<App />", () => {
  it("should not apply if no `onApply` prop provided", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);

    // expect ???;
  });
});
```

My question is: how can I test this behavior, since `onApply` must be a falsy value and so cannot be spied (as [Simon's stub docs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/))?

My testing stack is Enzyme, Chai and Sinon.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-empty-prop-91tml) is a working Codesandbox.

Also, I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357037/test-that-react-prop-method-has-not-been-called-with-jest) answer, that is the most similar problem I've found, but the suggestion in that question is check if `onApply`, in this case, is falsy, what is redundant, because I know it is when I pass it via props.